# Regarding path MTU discovery

Tags: networking, icmp, mtu

I have 4 machines

```
A <--> RA <--> RB<-->B
```

The machines are linked in internal network on VirtualBox, and the default mtu value was not changed.

In sending a packet larger than the local MTU(from A to B) ,I receive from the local IP

```
ping: local error: Message too long, mtu=1500
```

Should not the router instead send me back an ICMP type 3 code 4 packet?

Answer (score 0):

probabaly you are pinging with DF (Do not fragment) bit set. and the size of packet has already exceed the Router's link MTU. so ping generated an local error which is saying the message is too long.
the packet has not send out from Router. so you will not receive reply (type 3 code 4 from router B).